# How to append new images to the array using react native image crop picker?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

[image]

Hi, I am using react-native-image-crop-picker to overcome the above-shown module to select images from the gallery and display it in react native app, but I also want to click on add photo and again select images from the gallery and append them to the previous array of photos, am unable to figure that out.

This is the exact code that I have written to achieve the above-shown behavior, what should I change or add to perform the append feature?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const App = () => {
  const [photos, setAddPhotos] = useState(null);
  const [photo, setAddphoto] = useState(null);

 
  const handleChoosePhoto = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: false,
      includeExif: true,
      forceJpg: true,
    })
      .then((images) => {
        setAddphoto(null);
        setAddPhotos(
          images.map((i) => {
            console.log('recieved image', i);
            return {
              uri: i.path,
              // width: i.width,
              // height: i.height,
              width: 185,
              height: 128,
              mime: i.mime,
            };
          }),
        );
      })
      .catch((e) => alert(e));
  };

  const renderImage = (image) => {
    return (
      <Image
        style={{
          width: 185,
          height: 128,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          marginTop: 1,
        }}
        source={image}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderAsset = (image) => {
    return renderImage(image);
  };



  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {console.log('PHOTOS', photos)}
      {photos === null ? (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View style={Styles.headerWrapper}>
            <View
              style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <Icon name="angle-left" size={30} />
              <TouchableOpacity style={{right: '10%', top: '2%'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                  SAVE AND EXIT
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text style={Styles.headerText}>Add photos to your listing</Text>
            <Text style={Styles.subHeader}>
              Photos help guests imagine staying in your place. You can start
              with one and add more after you publish.
            </Text>
            <View style={Styles.container}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleChoosePhoto()}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#20B2AA',
                    width: 150,
                    height: 40,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#fff',
                      textAlign: 'center',
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }}>
                    Add photos
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              right: '5%',
              position: 'absolute',
              bottom: 10,
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                borderColor: '#20B2AA',
                borderWidth: 1,
                alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                padding: 10,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#20B2AA'}}>
                Skip For Now
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={Styles.headerWrapper}>
              <View
                style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <Icon name="angle-left" size={30} />
                <TouchableOpacity style={{right: '10%', top: '2%'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                    SAVE AND EXIT
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
              <View style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                {photos
                  ? photos.map((i) => (
                      <View
                        style={{
                          // width: 185, height: 128,

                          //  width:'50%',
                          flexBasis: '33.33%',
                        }}
                        key={i.uri}>
                        {renderAsset(i)}
                      </View>
                    ))
                  : null}
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <TouchableOpacity
       
              style={{
                alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                right: '5%',
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 10,
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#20B2AA',
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#FFF'}}>
                  NEXT
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerWrapper: {
    width: deviceWidth,
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 28,
    paddingLeft: 24,
  },
  container: {
    padding: 24,
  },
  subHeader: {
    paddingLeft: 24,
    fontSize: 17,
    paddingTop: 24,
    paddingRight: 24,
  },
});
```

Please let me know if anything else is required for better understanding, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to take the prevState in setAddPhotos

```
setAddPhotos((lastPhotos) => {
                                            const imagesMap = images.map((i) => {
                                                return {
                                                    uri: i.path,
                                                    width: i.width,
                                                    height: i.height,
                                                    mime: i.mime,
                                                };
                                            });
                                            return [...lastPhotos, ...imagesMap];
                });
```